# What need for an automatic design project? My project is very slow

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

After showing the house to the forge viewer using a Ravit file, the user wants to modify the contents of the viewer and receive it as a Ravit file again. What function should I use to implement the above?

https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/
I referred to it.

[my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAf8B.png)

I make input data and transfer this to design automation and get output file and file to translate viewer (this is 2 minutes).

This process is very slow I want better then this process.

https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Its-Not-Too-Late-Automate-Using-Forge-Design-Automation-Inventor-2021#video

This video looks very fast on work process. How to get fast work process like this video?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Forge Viewer is a **viewer**, not an **editor**.

The Forge viewer displays the translated version of a seed CAD model, in this case, a Revit `RVT` BIM.

You cannot edit or modify the CAD seed file in the viewer.

To achieve such a modification, you have to either use the original modelling software, in this case, Revit on the Windows desktop, or you can use the [Forge Design Automation API for Revit](https://forge.autodesk.com/api/design-automation-cover-page/).

That is what was used to create the Inventor sample you refer to.

Oops... re-reading your question, I see that you are already using design automation yourself as well. Congratulations on that.

However, there is no guarantee on the turn-around time for this process. The video may very well have been edited to eliminate a waiting period, of the user creating the video may just have been very lucky to achieve a faster turn-around time.

I am checking for you with the Forge team whether they used any additional tricks to speed things up in the video or in the true real-time processing. They confirm:

For Revit, a basic DA job should take up to 30-40 secs for the processing time alone. The derivative job for translation to viewer format could take another minute. So, 2 mins is expected. The [sketch it demo video](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-sketchit-revit) has a timer on the side to indicate real time.

Comment: Your blog was very helpful when I studied revit api. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation. My pleasure entirely. I asked about the video, and Augusto confirms: no tricks are being used, just the normal DA4R functionality. the video shows the timer, but it’s accelerated for the presentation.

Comment: Thank you for check my example video.
lastly add to my question, my example video is include showing to attach door at wall. how to this? Is this Design Automation too?